# How to compile and run `tap` tests with `webpack`?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, tap

I can't find any right config to run `tap` (or `tape`) tests in the browser while compiling with `webpack + babel`.

Here is a dead simple example:

```
import test from 'tap';

test('random test', function(t){
    t.ok(true, 'great!');
});
```

Trying to compile the above generate following errors as nodejs modules aren't polyfilled:

```
ERROR in ./~/tap/lib/test.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'child_process' in /Users/arnaud/projects/chrome-tap/node_modules/tap/lib
 @ ./~/tap/lib/test.js 30:12-36

ERROR in ./~/tap/lib/test.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'module' in /Users/arnaud/projects/chrome-tap/node_modules/tap/lib
 @ ./~/tap/lib/test.js 33:13-30

ERROR in ./~/tap/lib/test.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/arnaud/projects/chrome-tap/node_modules/tap/lib
 @ ./~/tap/lib/test.js 34:9-22
```

Or with `tape`:

```
ERROR in ./~/tape/lib/default_stream.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/arnaud/projects/chrome-tap/node_modules/tape/lib
 @ ./~/tape/lib/default_stream.js 2:9-22
```

I can compile and run `tape` tests using `browserify + babel` but I’d be interested in using `webpack` instead.

Alternatively, is there any pure ES6 (ie non nodejs) TAP library?

Answer (score 4):

I use karma to run tape tests via webpack. [This blog post](http://rmurphey.com/blog/2015/07/20/karma-webpack-tape-code-coverage) was really helpful in helping me get it set up -- there are karma addons for tap, webpack and for istanbul (if you want coverage). Basically you tell karma you're using webpack, add your webpack config to your karma config, and make the webpack entry point a module that requires all of your spec modules.

I had to add

```
node: {
    fs: "empty"
}
```

to my testing webpack config to prevent a reference error somewhere along the way.